# What happens when a body swapped person gets killed? (Law - Ope Ope no Mi)

Tags: one-piece

Lets pick Sanji in Namis body for example.

Lets say Namis body would get killed? Which of the 2 would die?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible theory:

The wiki states that the body swap happens cause of the switching of the two persons hearts.

[Source OP wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Ope_Ope_no_Mi)

> Through this ability, Law can dismember people from a distance without harming them, lift, move or displace objects of any size and **switch peoples' "hearts"**, which is shown to effectively switch souls—Donquixote Doflamingo refers to this technique as the "Personality Transplant Surgery" (人格移植手術 Jinkaku Ishoku Shujutsu?).

So basically, the soul is bound to the heart.

Based on this fact i assume, it matters how the person gets killed.

**1. Stabbed in the Heart**

**Theory: Sanji dead, Nami alive**

Explanation:

If Namis body would get stabbed in the heart, i belief, Sanjis soul would be killed an there would be no chance for him for coming back. On the other hand, Law should be capable to return Namis heart to hear body and save her.

*(I also assume this has to happen in a short period of time, cause a body can't "survive without a heart)*

**2. Cut into pieces**

**Theory: Sanji alive, Nami dead**

Explanation:

If Namis body get cut or destroyed but the heart would be unharmed, i belief it would be possible to return Sanjis heart to his body. I'm not sure how strong Laws Ope Ope no Mi powers are and if he could restore Namis body.

(I don't go into detail if Sanji would be psychologically stable after Namis dead)

**Conclusion**

I am sure, there are some other possible ways and theories.
**The essential part includes that the soul is bound to the heart and the soul swap happens through the heart swap.**